# iOS developer settings without developer account

Tags: ios

I'd like to access network link conditioning settings in my iPhone.  I do not want to pay for a developer account.  How can I enable developer mode on my phone permanently?  Please don't end the instructions at 'create developer profile', I don't know how to do that, and from what I can tell a free profile expires after 30 days.